# Content Provider wirting to database while SimpleCursorAdapter reads from same table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm having trouble with the SQLite database in Android.

I've implemented a Content Provider and throught the app this works just perfect.

At several points within the app i have lists which implements a `LoaderManager` together with a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. And this works fine, too.

<s>Now I have a background thread which updates (meaning update, insert and delete) data in the db.</s>
I have an `IntentService` which downloads some information from a server and evaluates the given information. Based upon this the Service eighter updates/inserts or deletes some information (through the content provider).

As long as the user is not on an activity/fragment which implements a list (as described above) everything works fine. And it gets updated when the Service updates the database.

But when the User is on a Activity/Fragment which implements a list (as shown above) it crashes as soon as the service wants to update or insert some data. Funny is that the deletion works fine. For insert and update I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1593)
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1510)
...ContentProvider.insert(ContentProvider.java:297)
```

it points to the `db.udapte(...)` statement within the Content Provider.

My assumption is, that I get this error because the `SimpleCursorAdapter` has an opean (readable) pointer to the table, hence it's locked.

How can I solve this issue?

And yes, I'm using SQLCipher. But I'm also experiencing this problem with the default Andoird implementation.

Comment: It seems you're closing the db somewhere. Is it possible?

Comment: actually no, i have even implemented the following just above the update: `if(!db.isOpen())db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the Thread and the direct db access. You told you're using a ContentProvider for select. Why don't you use the ContentProvider methods for update, insert and delete operation? If you use just the ContentProvider, you're for sure using a single instance of SqliteOpenHelper in your project, while having more than one could cause your issue.

Comment: Ofcourse I'm suing teh content provider for all operations (select, update, insert, delete). Sorry if it was unclear

Comment: Can you pleas explain better your sentence: Now I have a background thread which updates (meaning update, insert and delete) data in the db. What thread you mean?

Comment: I have changed it above. Please let me know if it's better understandable